# cd to specific directory by using part of input string and wildcard

Tags: bash, wildcard

I have multiple files in different directories. They look like this

```
/home/usr/data/folder_K123_A01/file/Sample_K123_1_ID33/K123_1_ID33.txt
/home/usr/data/folder_J337_B02/file/Sample_J337_4_ID46/J337_4_ID46.txt
/home/usr/data/folder_L711_C03/file/Sample_L711_13_ID07/L711_13_ID07.txt
```

`A01`, `B02`, `C03` are generated by machine; not really specific. It can use `*` to autofilled those values.

If I want to move to `L711_13_ID07`'s directory, I use

```
cd /home/usr/data/folder_L711*/ -> tab, enter
cd /file
cd /Sample_L711_13_ID07
```

Right now, need to move among those directories quickly. So, trying to compose script `movequick.sh` to take input `filenames` and `cd` to each directory quickly.

Current code is

```
Filename=$1
FD=`echo $Filename|cut -f1 -d'_'`;
cd /home/usr/data/folder_$FD_*/file/Sample_$Filename/
```

I do

```
./movequick L711_13_ID07
```

But, system gives me

```
line 3: cd: /home/usr/data/folder_L711_*/file/Sample_L711_13_ID07/: No such file or directory
```

I think I am missing one tab. I am also trying to put this script into my `.bashrc` to assure I can move around quick.

Need some advise. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
filename="$1"
fd="${filename%%_*}"
cd /home/usr/data/folder_"${fd}"_*/file/Sample_"${filename}"/
```

Important to use `${fd}` as you are using `_` after this variable name and `_`. In the variable name `$fd_` underscore is considered part of variable name.

Comment: I changed the code to 
cd /home/usr/data/folder_L711*/file/Sample_L711_13_ID07/ But, I still cannot go to the directory. Does my command correct?

Comment: What does `ls -l /home/usr/data/folder_L711*/file/Sample_L711_13_ID07/` show to you? Does `ls -l /home/usr/data/folder_L711_C03/file/Sample_L711_13_ID07/` work?

Answer (score 0):

When the folders are generated once and fixed after that, you can set up a bunch of aliases like

```
cdk123="cd /home/usr/data/folder_K123_A01/file/Sample_K123_1_ID33/K123_1_ID33.txt"
cdj337="cd /home/usr/data/folder_J337_B02/file/Sample_J337_4_ID46/J337_4_ID46.txt"
cdl711="cd /home/usr/data/folder_L711_C03/file/Sample_L711_13_ID07/L711_13_ID07.txt"
```

Put these in .bashrc and after login (or sourcing the file) you can use things like `cdk123`.
When the folders are fixed during your login session, you can generate these aliases from the `.bashrc`.
When it is variable during your session, you can use wildcards in your cd command:

```
cd /home/usr/data/*/*/*L711_13_ID07
```

Do you want to use TAB, you do not need to use enter all the time:
If you want to move to L711_13_ID07's directory, use

`cd /home/usr/data/folder_L711` -> tab `f` -> tab `S` -> tab ENTER
Play with the tab option before trying to use a script. When bash doesn't know which file/folder you want (two dirs both starting with f), hit tab again: after 2 tabs you see a list of possibilities. Add some letters and hit tab again.

And when you have cd commands in your history, try `^r cd` and hit `^r` until you see something.